# can you help me with my function on how to add events on a custom calendar?

Tags: php, jquery, html, windows

here is my code i usually checked it many times but i did'nt find the bug that stopping me from adding events on my calendar i need to find the bug so i ask a question hope you can help me to fix my issue can you help find the bug please thanks you so much for helping me in advance here is my code below..

```
      <div id="event_add" class="none">
        <p>Add Event on <span id="eventDateView"></span></p>
        <p><b>Event Title: </b><input type="text" id="eventTitle" value=""/>
      </p>
        <input type="hidden" id="eventDate" value=""/>
        <input type="button" id="addEventBtn" value="Add"/>
      </div>

      <?php
      echo '<a href="javascript:;" 
      onclick="addEvent(\''.$currentDate.'\');">add event</a>';
      ?>

     <script>
      function addEvent(date){
        $('#eventDate').val(date);
        $('#eventDateView').html(date);
        $('#event_list').slideUp('slow');
        $('#event_add').slideDown('slow');
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#addEventBtn').on('click',function(){
            var date = $('#eventDate').val();
            var title = $('#eventTitle').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'functions.php',
            data:'func=addEvent&date='+date+'&title='+title,
            success:function(msg){
            if(msg == 'ok'){
            var dateSplit = date.split("-");
            $('#eventTitle').val('');
            alert('Event Created Successfully.');
            getCalendar('calendar_div',dateSplit[0],dateSplit[1])
            &nbnbsp;      
            }     
            else{
                alert('Some problem occurred, please try again.');
                }
            }
         });
        });
       });
      </script>

      <?php
       function addEvent($date,$title){
        include 'dbConfig.php';
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO events (title,date,start,end) 
  VALUES ('".$title."','".$date."','".$currentDate."','".$currentDate."')");
      if($insert)
      {
        echo 'ok';
      }
      else{
          echo 'err';
      }
     }?>
```

Comment: what happens when you click on the href?

Comment: its connected to my JS so that when you click the input box will appear then you can create a new event but when i adding new events the JS function does'nt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we resolved this issue in the comments: The solution is to replace `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST`.

Another thing: It is considered bad practise to mix HTML, JS and PHP all in one file in this manner. It's better to keep things seperated, especially JS.

Comment: thanks Jonathan but the $currentdate you referring i got that defined but i didn't include the code because i only need to know how am i going to add events on my calendar :(

Comment: Can you give me an example of an event you'd like to add? Like this: When X happens, do Y.

Comment: i already put the whole code on codepad you can check it. just a simple event like "My Event"

Comment: So in Line 142, when #addEventBtn is clicked, nothing happens? Did you try to debug with alter() or console.log()?

Comment: yes when i click add event button nothing is happening that's why i asked some help :( hope you can help me fix this sir

Comment: In Line 143 I've added an alert() call. Can you run it in your codebase, click #addEventBtn and see if it fires?

Comment: it did'nt responded :(

Comment: The it seems like the button is created after the DOM has loaded, which means that the onclick handler in JS doesn't work. In other words: When the DOM has finished loading, the onclick handler is created for #addEventBtn. But JS doesn't find any element with that ID, so the handler isn't created.

If you seek further assistance, please post a link to a working demo. From now on, anything else would be guessing.

Comment: thanks jonathan i already fix the add i can add now the bug was i need to set the $_POST into -> $_REQUEST :) thanks for helping me debugging my error thank you..

Comment: Alirght, your're welcome! I've added the solution into my post. You might wannt to consider marking it as the answer. Onwards! :)